# How do I handle multi-resolution images for various levels of HiDPI scaling in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, hidpi

There are many scaling factors out there for HiDPI screens (1.25x, 1.5x, 2x, 3x, etc). The most straight-forward solution would be to provide multiple versions of the same image in JavaFX, which [seems to be possible in Swing](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8151787) using things like `@125pct` for 1.25x or `@2x` for 2x. Does this also work in JavaFX? If it doesn't, how should I load images to make sure they look crisp regardless of the HiDPI screen?

I have read here and there that JavaFX supports `@2x` but I haven't found any official piece of documentation actually stating it.

(As a side note, I would rather not use SVG images due to unrelated issues with Batik and the insane amount of dependencies this would pull in)

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX-8 (as well as JavaFX-11) only supports @2x - found by inspecting the code (search for ImageStorage in your IDE)

Comment: This only mentions @ 2x though, are things like @ 125pct supported? (Putting spaces because stack overflow thinks i'm mentioning people)

Comment: I corrected my answer - JavaFX only supports @ 2x if I read the code correctly